# ./node_modules/material-ui-icons/AccessAlarm.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/SvgIcon'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i am getting following errors, everything was working fine out of no where suddenly i got this error
[image]
./node_modules/material-ui-icons/AccessAlarm.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/SvgIcon'

i use   material ui icon following version.

"material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.36",

Comment: Don't you think it is @material-ui/icons?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing using the following code:

```js
import AccessAlarmIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccessAlarm';
```

Worked for me.